# count each element inside jsonObject using java stream

Tags: java, json, java-stream

I have a json Structure like this

```
[{
                "startAt": 1617605301292,
                "endAt": 1617605317095,
                "duration": 15803,
                "selection": {
                    "selected.Speed": "0",
                    "selected.Low": "65535",
                    "selected.Fast": "7173",
                    "selected.medium": "5"
                },
                "details": {
                    "phase": [{
                        "value": "2",
                        "timestamp": 1617605301316
                    }]
                }
            },....]
```

I need the count of every item inside selection  object.

For Example

- 0 occurred 4 times
- 65535 occurred 2 times
- 7173 occurred 3 times
- 5 occurred 1 times

this is what I have done so far

```
Map<String, Long> counted = jObj.stream()
                        .filter(y -> ((Map<String, Object>) y.get("selection")).containsKey("selected.Speed"))
                        .map(x -> {
                            String Speed = String.valueOf(((Map<String, Object>) x.get("details"))
                                    .get("selected.Speed"));
                            return Speed;
                        }).collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

so from this I am able to get the count of a single key but not the every key inside json Object.
Pardon if this is a very basic question, I am new to the stream.

TIA

Comment: You are reading values from another entry than the one expected to hold the values `x.get("details")` which should be `x.get("selection")`. Is that the actual JSON or is there any intermediate processing step? And are you looking for values i.e. *3 times*, *1 time*... mapped to each property key? (i.e. *0* for *selected.Speed* occurred *4 times*)

Comment: @tmarouane yes you are right I am looking for the same
like `0 selected.Speed occurred 4 times
65535 selected.Low occurred 2 time etc` actually based on that I need to prepare a json which will be like this
`[{
"selected.Low ":65535,
"count":2
},{
"selected.Low ":0,
"count":4
}
]`

Comment: Makes more sense. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `Stream#mapMulti`

If you're using [java-16](/questions/tagged/java-16), you can already make use of `Stream#mapMulti` for this use case. Here is how to solve it with this. If you're not using [java-16](/questions/tagged/java-16) yet, scroll further to find the traditional solution to the problem

```java
Map<String, Long> counted = jObj.stream()
        .map(x -> (Map<String, Object>) x.get("details"))
        .filter(x -> x.containsKey("selected.Speed"))
        .map(Map::values)
        .mapMulti((Collection<Object> collection, Consumer<String> consumer) -> {
            collection.forEach(element -> consumer.accept(String.valueOf(element)));
        })
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

With this solution, you don't have the overhead of an extra `Stream` creation

---

### Traditional approach

Normally this should solve it for you using `Stream#flatMap`, `Map#values` then `List#stream` and mapping every entry to a `String`

```java
Map<String, Long> counted = jObj.stream()
                        .filter(y -> ((Map<String, Object>) y.get("details")).containsKey("selected.Speed"))
                        .flatMap(x -> ((Map<String, Object>)x.get("details"))
                                                          .values()
                                                          .stream()
                                                          .map(String::valueOf))
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

You can even use an extra `map` intermediate operation to avoid casting `x.get("details")` to a `Map<String, Object>` twice

```java
Map<String, Long> counted = jObj.stream()
                        .map(x -> (Map<String, Object>) x.get("details"))
                        .filter(x -> x.containsKey("selected.Speed"))
                        .map(Map::values)
                        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                        .map(String::valueOf)
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

---

Here is the full test I've written for this

```java
List<Map<String, Object>> jObj = new ArrayList<>();
jObj.add(Map.of("details", Map.of("selected.Speed", "0", "selected.Low", "65535", "selected.Fast", "8000", "selected.medium", "5")));
jObj.add(Map.of("details", Map.of("selected.Speed", "1", "selected.Low", "32", "selected.Fast", "8000", "selected.medium", "5")));
jObj.add(Map.of("details", Map.of("selected.Speed", "2", "selected.Low", "32", "selected.Fast", "8000", "selected.medium", "5")));
jObj.add(Map.of("details", Map.of("selected.Speed", "0", "selected.Low", "65535", "selected.Fast", "8000", "selected.medium", "5")));


Map<String, Long> counted = jObj.stream()
        .map(x -> (Map<String, Object>) x.get("details"))
        .filter(x -> x.containsKey("selected.Speed"))
        .map(Map::values)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .map(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

System.out.println("counted = " + counted);
```

Which prints the expected result

```
counted = {0=2, 1=1, 2=1, 8000=4, 5=4, 65535=2, 32=2}
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any way I can get key as well with the output.
actually based on that I need to prepare a json which will be like this `[{ "selected.Low ":65535, "count":2 },{ "selected.Low ":0, "count":4 } ]`

Comment: Ok I guess this might be a second question @DoctorWho because the solution will differ quite much. [Can I ask only one question per post ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you should iterate through your JSON entries and process its fields:

```
jObj.stream()
    .map(x -> (Map<String, Object>) x.get("selection"))
    .filter(x -> x.containsKey("selected.Speed"))
    .flatMap(values -> values.entrySet().stream()) // flat-mapping entries to group them 
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey)) // group entries by their keys: `selected.Low`, `selected.Fast`...
    .entrySet()
    .stream() // streaming through grouped entries
    .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(
            e.getKey(),
            e.getValue().stream().map(Map.Entry::getValue).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())))
    ) // grouping entries values counts
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```